# Using spring-HATEOAS behind Secure protocol https

Tags: java, spring-hateoas

I'm using HATEOAS for my REST API which is behind https, but link stay in http.

```
"links": [
      {
        "rel": "self",
        "href": "http://..."
      },
      {
        "rel": "object",
        "href": "..."
      }
    ]
```

Is it possible to config HATEOAS to point on my https ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I resolved my problem by specifing the header as part of my virtual host configuration

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ServerName www.example.com

    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/server.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/server.key

    <Location/>
        SSLRequireSSL
    </Location>

    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:9000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:9000/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: This really helped me out! Thanks a lot! One note: if you implement this, don't forget to import module mod_headers.so

Comment: For `nginx`,  add the same using `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;`.  Check details under _Virtual Host File And Upstream Module_  section in the link [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-load-balancing-with-ssl-termination)

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way, via `ControllerLinkBuilder`:

```
Link selfLink = new Link(ControllerLinkBuilder.linkTo(methodOn(Mycontroller.class).someMethod()).toUriComponentsBuilder().scheme("https").build().toUriString(), Link.REL_SELF);
```

That should produce a `Link` with the self rel and a URI of the following form: https://host:port/contextroot/pathtocontrollermethod

Comment: Thanks but how can i use withSelfRel() and withRel() with this method ?

Comment: don't think its possible to use those convenience methods if you need access to the `UriComponentsBuilder`, but updated answer to show manual creation of the `Link` anyway.